# SQL: Is it possible to GROUP multiple columns individually

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have a table like this:

```
property1    property2    property3
21           a            car
354          d            car
76           c            basket
12           a            tape
```

Is it possible to run ONE query that returns data like this without UNION.

```
property1 has values: 21, 354, 761, 12
property2 has values: a, d, c
property3 has values: car, basket, tape
```

Or should I do this with PHP? The table can get very large, so I don't think pivot is an option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several databases implement `grouping sets` which might do exacdtly what you want.  In MySQL, you can use three separate columns:

```
select group_concat(distinct property1), group_concat(distinct property2), group_concat(distinct property3)
from t;
```

or `union all`:

```
select 'property1', group_concat(distinct property1)
from t
union all
select 'property2', group_concat(distinct property2)
from t
union all
select 'property3', group_concat(distinct property3)
from t;
```

As a note:  there is a system parameter for the maximum length of the `group_concat()` string.  You can change its value, if you need longer strings.

Comment: I would like to warn against group_concat solution, since it requires more attention when values can contain commas. Also, since the table can be big, one needs to remember of group_concat_max_len.

Comment: I wasn't looking for something with UNIONs since the table I'm using has some JOINs and has to be recreated everytime, but your first example did the trick. A lot faster than the mess that I've made. Thanks!

Comment: @OlegKomarov: Good to know. Eventhough the table can become big, the different values per property are limited, so this answer is perfect. I'll have to keep it in mind though. Thanks